# my boxcutter creates 2 figures and cuts wrong

Tags: modeling, objects, add-on, transforms, workflow

I installed boxcutter on blender version 3.1.2 and can't work with it. when cutting, two figures are created, which do not disappear and the cutout works only with a cubic shape, and not the one I drew myself. sometimes noticed that the blender breaks when I press ctrl + z, basically, to cancel the cuts. how to fix this so I can work normally?
[1, selected box cut]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Czhna.png
[2, works bad]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YwbH.png

Comment: which version of boxcutter?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: @MartyFouts version 7.1 i guess. just opened release_log in a folder